# How to add custom LocaleResolverConfiguration in webflux

Tags: locale, spring-webflux

I added the following `@Bean` in the classpath for overriding default `LocaleContextResolver` in spring webflux

```java
@Configuration
public class LocaleResolverConfiguration {

  @Bean(WebHttpHandlerBuilder.LOCALE_CONTEXT_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
  public LocaleContextResolver localeContextResolver() {
    return new LocaleContextResolver() {
      @Override
      public LocaleContext resolveLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        final String langParam = exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().getFirst("lang");
        if (langParam == null) {
          return new SimpleLocaleContext(Locale.getDefault());
        } else {
          return new SimpleLocaleContext(Locale.forLanguageTag(langParam));
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void setLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange exchange, LocaleContext localeContext) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale context resolution strategy");
      }
    };
  }

}
```

But the application startup fails with the following error

`The bean 'localeContextResolver', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/acme/webflux/config/LocaleResolverWebFluxConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.`

Why is webflux not backing off when we already provided our own `LocaleContextResolver localeContextResolver()`?

Is there some other way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following hack as I could not find any reasonable way to modify the `localeContextResolver` without getting rid of autoconfiguration. But this is just a hack, not a reasonable solution

```java
@Configuration
public class LocaleResolverConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner localeContextResolverCustomizer(HttpHandler httpHandler) {
    assert httpHandler instanceof HttpWebHandlerAdapter;
    return args -> {
      ((HttpWebHandlerAdapter) httpHandler).setLocaleContextResolver(new LocaleContextResolver() {
        @Override
        public LocaleContext resolveLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
          final String langParam = exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().getFirst("lang");
          if (langParam == null) {
            return new SimpleLocaleContext(Locale.getDefault());
          } else {
            return new SimpleLocaleContext(Locale.forLanguageTag(langParam));
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void setLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange exchange, LocaleContext localeContext) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot change HTTP parameter - use a different locale context resolution strategy");
        }
      });
    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In webflux I have used the following snippet of code and it works. If `lang` parameter is found in the URL so the associated messages are resolved, else it resolves messages associated to HTTP request header `Content-Language`. If both are not set, so default messages with be resolved:

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleResolverConfig {

   @Bean
   @ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
   public HttpHandler httpHandler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
       HttpHandler delegate = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(applicationContext).build();
       return new HttpWebHandlerAdapter(((HttpWebHandlerAdapter) delegate)) {
       @Override
       protected ServerWebExchange createExchange(
           ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
                ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange = super.createExchange(request, response);

                final MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = request.getQueryParams();
                final String languageValue = queryParams.getFirst("lang");
                if (StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(languageValue)) {
                     LocaleContextHolder.setLocaleContext(() -> 
                          Locale.forLanguageTag(languageValue));
                } else {
                     LocaleContext localeContext = serverWebExchange.getLocaleContext();
                     if (localeContext != null) {
                          LocaleContextHolder.setLocaleContext(localeContext);
                     }
                }
                return serverWebExchange;
           }
       };
    }
 }
```